# Can not show new contents in window which are added in back ground

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt, and I am developing a windows application with Qt 5.3.1. I have a main window (called window A), which will listen to meeting events from SOCKET IO server, list all active meetings within it. When user click a meeting, the main window will hide, and open a window (called window B) to join the meeting. At the same time, window A is still listening to meeting events and will add new incoming meeting requests. Window A works well when it's active. But when I open window B, and new meeting requests coming, new meeting requests can not show within window A.

[image: There are 4 meetings in below screen shot(Window A), 1,3,4 are created when Window A is active, 2nd is created when Window A is hidden]

I am using a customized widget and layout to show meetings in 2 columns.
As above screen shot show, meetings 1, 3, and 4 are created when Window A is active, while meeting 2 is created when Window A is hidden.
I created a widget called MeetingListView to show meetings, and when Window A is active again, will call MeetingListView's slot forceUpdateUI. 
Below are forceUpdateUI source code:

```
 void MeetingListView::forceUpdateUI(){
        qDebug()<<"MeetingListView::forceUpdateUI count="<<mMeetingList.length();
        int count = mLayout->count();
        for(int i=count-1; i>=0; i--){
            //Remove all meeting items
            MeetingItem *item = (MeetingItem*)(mLayout->itemAt(i)->widget());
            item->setParent(nullptr);
            mLayout->removeItem(i);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<mMeetingList.length(); i++){
            //Add all meeting items again
            MeetingItem *item = mMeetingList.at(i);
            mLayout->addWidget(item);
        }
        mLayout->update();
    }
```

However, it doesn't work at all.

Latest update:
I created a layout class inherit from QGridLayout, instead of QLayout, now the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*I think* it is because each window has it own events loop. Going in the events loop of B from a A callback prevents the loop of A to continue.

You must launch a non-modal version of B, and then return from the callback from A, to let the loop continue (or manually launch the B window in another thread).

You can hide the A window while the B is shown to prevent the user from opening other B windows (since the A loop is still active).